# Create variable to JavaScript array from another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a function that create and store an array for all the p elements:

```
function dummyArray(){

    var $dummy= $('p');
    var dummy= [];
    i = 0;

    $dummy.each(function()
    {
            dummy[i++] =$(this).html();
    });     

    return dummy;
}
```

Now, in order to reuse the array in another function, I can use dummyArray() and dummyArray()[0] to access the individual data.

```
function initAll(){
    //dummyArray();
    //dummyArray()[0];
}
```

However I want to store it inside a variable like below but it gives me error.

```
function initAll(){
    var allArray = dummyArray();//error
}
```

Is there a way to store it inside a variable or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Chang this line `dummy[i++] =$(this).html();` to `dummy.push($(this).html());`

Answer (score 0):

After cleaning up my code I noticed that using var allArray = dummyArray(); does work, the error was generated from something else. cheers~

Edited:
The error I found out was the function name cannot be the same as the new variable name declared even though the () aren't there.

```
var dummyArray = dummyArray();//error
var allArray = dummyArray();//works
```